# How can we pick $f \in C(0,T;H)$ with $f(T) =0$ and $f(0) = h$, where $h$ is arbitrary?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

Let $C(0,T;H)$ be the space of continuous functions $f:[0,T]\to H$ where $H$ is Hilbert.

For every $h \in H$, why is it possible to pick a function $f \in C(0,T;H)$ such that $f(0) = h$ and $f(T) = 0$?

When $H = \mathbb{R}$, OK, I guess it's possible to do this as i can visualise a graph. But not sure about the general case. How to prove it?

---

I ask because I see in the proof to parabolic PDE existence, one gets
$$(u_0-u(0),v(0))_H=0$$
for all $v \in C(0,T;H)$ with $v(T)=0$, and from this everybody says that $u(0) = u_0$ since $v(0)$ is arbitrary. So this is why I ask the question.

Comment: What's wrong with $f(t)=\frac{T-t}{T}h$ as in the real case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H$ is a Hilbert space, so is also a vector space (over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$). In addition, $H$ has an *inner product* $< , >$.

Pick a point $h \in H$.
Consider the map $t \mapsto th$, where $t \in  \mathbb{R}$ and $h \in H$. $\lVert th - sh \rVert^2 =\ <th-sh, th-sh>$, since the Hilbert space norm is defined using its inner product.
Then,
$$\lVert th - sh \rVert^2  =\ <th-sh, th-sh>\ =\ (t-s)^2<h,h>\ =\ (t-s)^2 \lVert h \rVert ^2$$
and so
$$\lVert th - sh \rVert =  |t-s| \lVert h \rVert $$
This shows that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to H$ given by $f(t) = (1 - \frac{t}{T})h$ is continuous, because
$$\lim \limits _{s \to t}\lVert f(t) - f(s) \rVert = \lim \limits _{s \to t}\lVert (1 - \frac{t}{T})h - (1 - \frac{s}{T})h \rVert = \lim \limits _{s \to t}\frac{|t-s|}{T} \lVert h \rVert = 0$$
Since $f$ is continuous, it is in $C(0,T;H)$ by definition.